# Installing mod_ssl on CentOS

Tags: centos, yum, mod-ssl

I am trying to install mod_ssl on my server with:

```
yum install mod_ssl
```

All i get in response is:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centosv4-msync-dvd.centos.org
 * extras: centosq4-msync-dvd.centos.org
 * updates: centosv4.centos.org
Setting up Install Process
No package mod_ssl available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I am trying to install a self signed SSL-certificate, and I realized I was missing mod_ssl when I couldn't find the ssl.conf file.

How can I install mod_ssl?

Repolist

```
repo id                       repo name                                status
base                          CentOS-6 - Base                          5,932+362
extras                        CentOS-6 - Extras                                4
updates                       CentOS-6 - Updates                          261+65
repolist: 6,197
```

Comment: Are you really using CentOS4, which is about to be desupported?

Comment: Hm, my CentOS 4 has mod_ssl. You may want to check that you have reasonable yum repositories in your /etc/yum.repos.d.

Comment: Do a `yum repolist` and post it...

Comment: added the repolist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

and also try

```
yum search mod_ssl
```

then

`yum install mod_ssl.XX` <- as listed from yum search output.

if you can't find any of the packages try and install source forge repo, it has thousands of packages and mod_ssl is there

Comment: This worked for me with RHEL7.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try clear cache:

```
yum clean packages
yum install mod_ssl
```